# Recover su password after modifying /etc/shadow

Tags: linux, login, root, su, system-recovery

I follow [a tutorial about the race condition exploit](http://www.cgsecurity.org/Articles/SecProg/Art5/index-fr.html).

I made a copy of my /etc/shadow file.
And then replace all the contain by one line

```
root::1:99999:::::
```

However. My old password doesn't work anymore when I'm trying to use the command su. :/

I kept my old shadow file but try to restore it. However I can't because I'm not su and can't become su anymore.

Does anyone know if it's possible to deduce which is the new su's password only with the line I provided above ?

I'm currently on Linux Mint 18.

Comment: Press <LeftCtrl>+<LeftAlt>+<F1>. Type "root". Press <Enter>. What does this do? After trying this, press <LeftCtrl>+<LeftAlt>+<F7> to get back to where you were.

Comment: @thb `F7` and greater are reserved for X sessions, but `F7` is only the right one if the user is the only (or first) person currently logged in, at least for Ubuntu's "Switch user" functionality.

Answer (score 7):

`root::…` is an empty password hash. Depending on how your system is configured (is `nullok` present on the `auth … pam_unix.so` line in `/etc/pam.conf` or the applicable file in `/etc/pam.d`?), you either get no password prompt, or else no password will be accepted.

Since `su` doesn't let you in, it probably isn't configured with `nullok`. That's to be expected: allowing login with no password for root is highly unusual so it isn't the default configuration.

If `su` or `login` is configured with `nullok_secure` then this allows you to log in with no password, but only on a text console. So try switching to a text console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) and logging in as root, or logging in under your normal account and running `su`.

If you have `sudo` set up then it doesn't care about the root password and you can still use it.

If you can't get into the root account this way, you'll have to reboot in single user mode or rescure shell mode. See [What is the difference between these two ways of reseting the root password?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/191618/what-is-the-difference-between-these-two-ways-of-reseting-the-root-password), [How to Reset Forgotten Root Password in Fedora 19 from GRUB](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85558/how-to-reset-forgotten-root-password-in-fedora-19-from-grub), [How can we change root password?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35929/how-can-we-change-root-password/85241), …

In the future, if you do anything that might affect logging in, keep a root shell open!

Comment: thb, It work perfectly ! I just needed to press CRTL LEFT + ALT LEFT. Type "root". Press ENTER It didn't ask me any password.

As @Gilles said, I think that it wasn't configured with "nullok" when I type "su"

When was maybe configure using CRTL LEFT + ALT LEFT + F1Type "root". Press ENTER

Thanks everyone