# Recovering /etc/passwd file

Tags: passwd, etc, system-recovery

I deleted my `/etc/passwd` with my fat fingers.

I saw that there is a `/etc/passwd-` that looks like a backup file but I cannot copy it to restore the original one since I can't `sudo` anymore.

My volume is encrypted.

Is there a way to recover it from the backup copy?

**EDIT**: After rebooting to apply the fix, the `passwd-` file was empty...
I should have done a copy of it while it was still possible.
So, am I screwed?

Comment: Boot from a recovery disk, mount the partition then cp the file.

Answer (score 4):

Boot with `init=/bin/bash` at the Grub prompt. Supply the encryption password when prompted. Run the following commands:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
cp -a /etc/passwd- /etc/passwd
mount -o remount,ro /
reboot
```

If your system uses SELinux, [you may need to run `touch /.autorelabel`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85558/how-to-reset-forgotten-root-password-in-fedora-19-from-grub/125773#125773).

Akternatively, boot from a recovery disk, mount the partition then cp the file. – @Bib

Comment: I will do it at the end of my day since now I am still using my active session to work. 
Is it gonna be fine with the encrypted volume?
When you mention boot with `init=/bin/bash`, can you be more specific?
Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: @zakrapovic See e.g. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1102836/after-accidentally-renaming-etc-how-do-i-rename-it-back/1102854#1102854 for more dtailed instructions to reach a root shell

Comment: You'll be fine since you're using `initrd` which will ask for a decryption password and will set up your root partition for you.

Comment: Your solution should have worked, but after rebooting the passswd- file was empty. I should have copied it. So I don't have anmore any original of the file. Am I screwed for good?

Comment: Please boot into recovery again and post the output of `ls -la /etc/passwd*` and `cat /etc/passwd-`.